# ics file sended to outlook are not reconized as event

Tags: java, email, icalendar

I need to develop an application to send events to Gmail / Outlook calendars. Java mail 1.5.5 is used. I did some tests with version 1.6.2, without more success
The chosen solution is to generate ics files, and send them by email to the target calendars adresses.

On Gmail, the email is well recognized as an event email (the email contains the description of the event, the possibility to change the answer, and the event is automatically added to the calendar)

On Outlook, the attachment is not recognized as an event (the email just contains the ics file as an attachment, no description or response request, and the event is not automatically added to the calendar) . You must then click on the attachment, then on "Add to calendar" so that the event is created in the calendar

I found many similar topics on the net, but nothing that helped me solve the problem

The problem could come from the ics file or the headers of the mail. The ics file looks good to me: If on gmail, I create a new message, I add my ics as an attachment, and I send it to my Outlook address, the email is well recognized as an event

Here is the content of the ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:<MYPRODID>
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220629T121224Z
SUMMARY:Test Event
DTSTART:20220630T110000Z
DTEND:20220630T130000Z
UID:<MYUID>
SEQUENCE:1656460800
DESCRIPTION:Event body
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=FALSE;CN=<MYCN>:mailto:<MYEMAIL>
ORGANIZER;CN=<MYORGNAME>:mailto:<MYORGEMAIL>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have some doubt on the headers / mail structure. I find a lot of different things on the internet, but everything I try leads to the same result (the need to open my email in Outlook, to manually import the attachment)

Here is my java code during the last tests:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.put("mail.mime.charset", "UTF-8");
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "<MYHOST>");
prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "<MYPORT>");
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
prop.put("mail.smtp.user", "<MYUSER>");
prop.put("password", "<MYPASS>");

String from = "<MYORGEMAIL>";
String to = "<MYEMAIL>";

Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new SMTPAuthenticator(prop));
// Define message
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.addHeader("method", "REQUEST");
message.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
message.addHeader("component", "VEVENT");

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message.setSubject("Outlook Meeting Request Using JavaMail");

File invitation = new File("<MYFILEPATH>\\vCalendar_5067936453064913847.ics");

MimeMultipart mixed = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

// Create the message part
MimeMultipart alternative = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
MimeBodyPart alternativePart = new MimeBodyPart();
alternativePart.setContent(alternative);
mixed.addBodyPart(alternativePart);
MimeBodyPart plain = new MimeBodyPart();
plain.setText("body", "UTF-8", "plain");
MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
html.setText("<div dir=\"ltr\">body</div>", "UTF-8", "html");
alternative.addBodyPart(plain);
alternative.addBodyPart(html);

// Create the attachment part
BodyPart icsBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
icsBodyPart.addHeader("method", "REQUEST");
icsBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
icsBodyPart.addHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
icsBodyPart.addHeader("component", "VEVENT");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(invitation.getAbsolutePath());
final DataSource source =
    new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream,
        "text/calendar; charset=\"UTF-8\"; name=\"vCalendar_5067936453064913847.ics\"");
icsBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
icsBodyPart.setFileName(invitation.getName());
mixed.addBodyPart(icsBodyPart);

// Put parts in message
message.setContent(mixed);

// send message
Transport.send(message);
```

To know how to structure my mime parts, I look to my message structure in my gmail sendbox (the one that is reconized by Outlook) :

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2022 14:44:10 +0200
Message-ID: <XXXXXXXXXXX@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Mail title test
From: XXXXXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com>
To: XXXXXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXX.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="00000000000072927505e39b0616"

--00000000000072927505e39b0616
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000072927005e39b0614"

--00000000000072927005e39b0614
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Mail content test

--00000000000072927005e39b0614
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">Mail content test<br></div>

--00000000000072927005e39b0614--
--00000000000072927505e39b0616
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="UTF-8"; name="vCalendar_5067936453064913847.ics"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="vCalendar_5067936453064913847.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_l4i5zybk0
Content-ID: <f_l4i5zybk0>
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--00000000000072927505e39b0616--
```

If I knew how to see the same informations on outlook, I could compare the mail received from gmail and the one received from java, but I'm not sure it's possible (I found the "display / message details" option, but this option only show informations about the top level mime part, not the complete mime structure)

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to save an existing event to an ics file and then try to compare them to find any difference between a generated by your code one and saved.

Comment: Compare an email with an ics that Outlook recognizes to the ones you send. You may have to look at the mime structure / plain text of the email.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, as I said, I'm pretty sure that the ics is OK (If my ics is send from gmail, outlook reconizes it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the mime structure, I only succed to see it in gmail, not in Outlook. I use this mail structure to write my java code, I edit my question to add informations about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a solution in rewriting a `Content-Type` header. I've added `method=REQUEST` to this header and after that outlook started recognize my emails as events.

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST
```

Example of code on python:

```py
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Your event'
msg['From'] = 'test@test.com'
msg['To'] = 'test@test.com'

with open('example.ics') as f:
    event = MIMEText(f.read(), _subtype='calendar', _charset='utf-8')
    event.replace_header('Content-Type', 'text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST')
    msg.attach(event)


s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

For your ics part in eml file,adding a `request` statement is necessary.

For your eml file,it may look like:

```bash
...
--00000000000072927505e39b0616
Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset="UTF-8"; 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:<MYPRODID>
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220629T121224Z
SUMMARY:Test Event
DTSTART:20220630T110000Z
DTEND:20220630T130000Z
UID:<MYUID>
SEQUENCE:1656460800
DESCRIPTION:Event body
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=FALSE;CN=<MYCN>:mailto:<MYEMAIL>
ORGANIZER;CN=<MYORGNAME>:mailto:<MYORGEMAIL>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

--00000000000072927505e39b0616
```

The `request` can be `PUBLISH`,`REQUEST`,`REPLY`,`ADD`,`CANCEL`,`REFRESH` or `COUNTER`

And for your Java code,change

```java
final DataSource source =
    new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream,
        "text/calendar; charset=\"UTF-8\"; name=\"vCalendar_5067936453064913847.ics\"");
```

to

```java
final DataSource source =
    new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream,
        "text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=\"UTF-8\"; name=\"vCalendar_5067936453064913847.ics\"");
```